# Factory girl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I've written a rspec test which adds into my rubric some units.

I have two models => Rubric and Units. Rubrics have many units.
It looks like this:

```
@rubric.units.push Factory :text_unit
@rubric.save
```

Then I found factory_girl and tried to rewrite
this code as a factory. But it is not working.

How can i write this association in Factory Girl.
I tried this:

```
  factory :common_rubric , :class => :common_info_rubric do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) {|n| "common_info_rubric#{n}"}
  end

  factory :text_unit, :class => text_info_unit do |f|
    f.association :common_rubric_with_unit
    f.sequence(:name) {|n| "text_unit#n}" }
  end

  factory :common_rubric_with_unit , :parent => :common_rubric do |f|
    f.units { |unit| unit.association(:text_info_unit) }
  end
```

I always have error

```
SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
```

Comment: All problem was the undefault name of table in models. 
And after read 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl
i solve the problem. It it here http://pastie.org/2355251 (because i cant answer for my question until 7 hours left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All problem was the undefault name of table in models. 
And after read 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl
i solve the problem

```
 factory :common_rubric , :class => :common_info_rubric do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) {|n| "common_info_rubric#{n}"}
  end

  factory :text_unit, :class => :text_info_unit do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) {|n| "text_unit#{n}" }
  end

  factory :common_rubric_with_unit, :parent => :common_rubric do |f|
    f.after_create {|a| Factory(:text_unit, :rubric => a) }
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a circular reference there. When you create a `text_unit` it creates an associated `common_rubric_with_unit`. The definition for `common_rubric_with_unit` creates an associated `text_unit` and we're back at the start.

You'll need to remove one of the associations from either side, this should work:

```
factory :text_unit, :class => text_info_unit do |f|
  f.association :common_rubric_with_unit
  f.sequence(:name) {|n| "text_unit#n}" }
end

factory :common_rubric_with_unit , :parent => :common_rubric do |f|
end
```